# How to create React-Native tvos project?

Tags: xcode, react-native, tvos, apple-tv

all. I am having a hard time creating a project that can build and run. I can create normal iOS react-native projects without issue, but I don't understand the instructions for the tvos setup. Can someone please explain or simply tell me what lines to enter into the terminal? I am currently creating react native apps using npx (like npx react-native init myproject, npx react-native run-ios etc).

Here are some resources: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-for-apple-tv
This one says "The RNTester app supports Apple TV; use the RNTester-tvOS build target to build for tvOS.". I don't know what "RNTester app" is, or how to "use RNTester-tvos build target".

Also, I don't understand anything here: "https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tvos"

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while you posted but I had the same issue and finally figured it out:

Depending on your react-native-cli version you can do:

```react
react-native init TestApp --version=react-native@npm:react-native-tvos@latest
```

or

```react
react-native init TestApp --template=react-native-tvos@latest
```

TestApp is the name of your App

https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/react-native-tvos

Answer (score 0):

This has changed though. Follow the official instructions here:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Then, make sure you're not in a sub-folder of another npm project and that react-native-cli is not installed globally:

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli
```

Then you're ready to go:

```
npx react-native-tvos@latest init TestApp
```